# Mysql - Select To XML

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, parsing, audit-trail

I'm Building Audit Trail with Trigger, and want to convert the inserted / updated / deleted value into XML and store it into another table.

my trigger look like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `MyDB`.`TriggerAudit` AFTER INSERT
    ON `MyDB`.`settings`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_audit_trail (user_uid, table_name, inserted_value) 
    VALUES ('the Username', 'the table name', 'Select to XML In Here')
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Normally in MSSQL I can use FOR XML function, but in I Don't know to do this in MySQL.
Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't do it from a normal query, but you can dump contents from mysql providing a query into XML from the command line, like

```
shell> mysql --xml -uroot -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'"
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resultset statement="SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<field name="Variable_name">version</field>
<field name="Value">5.0.40-debug</field>
</row>
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml

not the same thing as calling from a trigger, I know :-(

Comment: Yeaa, I already know that. Hopefully they implemented that feature in the future.